# how to disable Shipping Method magento 2 Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to hide **shipping method** from my checkout page. I am working on a custom theme. I tried to removing shipping method through XML but didn't work that. Is there any way to hide this?

Comment: Disable it from your Magento backend

Comment: you can disable it in store>configuration>sales>shipping methods

Answer (score 1):

[image: Store>Configuration>Sales>Shipping Methods]

Go to

Store>Configuration>Sales>Shipping Methods

Select Shipping Method and set the Enabled field to No and then press the button Save Config.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sell virtual products just set product as virtual. 
No shipping methods will be visible or used in whole process.